# Making an API call with discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

So I'm trying to do a simple API call with a discord bot to get the prices of games on Steam. I have the API request working but when I try and trigger the bot to check the price for me nothing happens. I don't get an error in the console and the bot doesn't post anything to chat.

I know it's pretty ugly I'll go back and clean it up after I can get it to post.

```
if message.content.startswith('!pricecheck'):
    game = message.content[11:]
    gres = requests.get('https://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v2/')
    gdata = gres.json()
    for i in gdata["applist"]["apps"]:
        if (i["name"] == game):
            app = (i["appid"])
            priceres = requests.get(f"https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids={app}")
            priced = priceres.json()
            price = (priced[f"{app}"]["data"]["price_overview"].get("final"))
            msg = f"{game} is currently{price}".format(message)
            await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the command is called by `!pricecheck <game>`, `game = message.content[11:]` is including the space. See test case below, where space is replaced with _ so it's easily readable.

```
>>> test = '!pricecheck_gamename'
>>> print(test[11:])
_gamename
```

Because of this, `if (i["name"] == game)` is never True, so `await client.send_message` will never execute.

Changing it to `message.content[12:]` will remove the space.

---

**Suggestions**

Adding a check to see if a game was found will allow you to see when all your `if` evaluates to `False`. It also gives users feedback when the command did not work, possibly because of incorrect usage.

You can also change the `requests` library to the [`aiohttp`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library, which is the asynchronous version. `requests` can be dangerous as it is blocking, meaning that if it takes to long it can cause your code to crash.

Below is an example of how these suggestions can be used with your code.

```
game_found = False
for i in gdata["applist"]["apps"]:
    if (i["name"] == game):
        game_found = True
        app = (i["appid"])
        session = aiohttp.ClientSession()
        priceres = await session.get(f"https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails/?appids={app}")
        priced = await priceres.json()
        session.close()
        price = (priced[f"{app}"]["data"]["price_overview"].get("final"))
        msg = f"{game} is currently{price}".format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
if not game_found:
    await client.send_message(message.channel, f"Could not find info on {game}"
```

Comment: This is great thank you! I will checkout the aiohttp library I haven't heard of it before. I'm currently using requests_cache to speed up searches against the main game list.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include `aiohttp` in the example code